# Symfony code logout not reached angular

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony

I've got a little problem and I really don't know how to resolve it. I'm trying to implement the logout in symfony using also angular 1x.
Some of my code is:

```
 <button ui-sref='logout'>...</button>
```

angular:

```
 .state('logout', {
       url: '/logout',
       controller: 'LogoutController',
       resolve: ....
       } 
  )
```

routing.yml

```
 path: /logout
 defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:logout }
 method: [POST]
```

UserController(AppBundle):

```
 public function logoutAction(Request request){
    $something = ""; // if I put breakpoint here it doesn't enter at all
 }
```

LogoutController:

```
 .controller('LogoutController', function($scope) {
   $scope.logout = function(){   //I don't have the code available right now but the alg is something like this:
      localStorage.remove(sessionId);
      window.location = '#/login'
   }

   $scope.logout();
  }
```

The last angular part is working, it redirects me to login page, but I cannot access the symfony part and I don't know why. The url from state should match the routing path, and then to access the logout method from the user controller. But it doesn't. Any ideas? What have I missed?

Comment: are you using a fullstack with symphony or,  something like. you have an api and a front apart each one ? .

Comment: @JesusCarrasco sorry, I don't understand what you mean.. why are you asking me that?

Comment: i comment because if you using separate architectures, you need to implement a service wich call the endopoint logout in your front.

Comment: if you using a fullstack the all the funcitonality of session correspond to symphony, cause himself render the app, but if you have separate the front and back, needs to comunicate via ajax, how do you login to you app ?.

Comment: @Jesus Carrasco Thats the point, the login is almost implemented in the same manner as the logout. The email & pass are sent into the action method from controller, some events occurs checking the user and loaded and also I have the angular part, where I also set the session into local storage..

Comment: i think you need to call in some service the path logout of your backend. try `$http({method:post, data:sessionID, url:'logout'}) ` and in the success. clean your localstroage an redirect to login page.

Comment: @JesusCarrasco I will try, thank you. But I thought that in $state its made the route calling: url: /logout.

Comment: can you share how to login, with that i will understand how is your app architecture builded.  i mean, if you sesssion is based on tokens or is the fullstack who manage the session, for what i see you storage an a session on the client, thats whay i suppose you have an spa. and api.

Comment: Yes, I have an api.. sorry for not saying you this first time

Comment: the login form. use a subtmit to a path ('/login') or do something in the controller with an $http service???.

Comment: The first choice, I resumed it earlier the login implementation..